# Determine if correct route was taken

Tags: c#

I'm developing a C# Winforms app where I need to determine if a truck took a specifed route, and passed through the points in the correct order.  An example of valid routes would be as follows:

**ROUTE 1**
Entry gate 1
Scale gate entry side
Scale gate exit side
Exit gate 1

**ROUTE 2**
Entry gate 2
Scale gate entry side
Scale gate exit side
Exit gate 2

The scale gates are the same for both routes, but the entry and exit gates are what I need to worry about.  If a truck enters in through gate 1 and exits through the gate 1, then the route followed was correct.  However, if a truck enters gate 2 and exits through gate 1, then I need to send a notification.

Each gate has hardware configured as a read point.  When the truck passes the read point a record is created in the database with the timestamp.  I have a timer set up so that at the specified interval it retrieves a list of the valid the truck ID's.  It then retrieves the read points that each truck passed within a specified time period and stores those in a list as well.  What I'm not sure of is how to compare the "correct route" list with the list of read points that the truck passed.  Right now I'm going on the basis that each truck will only make the trip once a day, and will tweak for additional trips after I get this covered.

Here's my code for the timer

```
private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int maxTime = int.Parse(AppSettings.GetAppSetting("MaxTime"));
        List<string> _assets = new List<string>();
        List<ReadPoint> _assetReads = new List<ReadPoint>();

        //Get the list of assets to process
        DataSet ds = du.ExecuteTextCommand("SELECT DISTINCT AssetId FROM " + 
             "(SELECT a.TagId, a.AssetId, a.Description, rp.Comments, DateScanned " + 
             "FROM AssetsReads ar JOIN Assets a on ar.AssetTagID = a.AssetTagID " + 
             "JOIN ReadPointLocations rp on " + 
             "ar.ReadPointLocationsID = rp.ReadPointLocationsID) AS AssetResult " + 
             "ORDER BY AssetId");
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                _assets.Add(dr["AssetId"].ToString());
            }
        }

        //Loop through and process the assets
        foreach (string asset in _assets)
        {
            ds = du.ExecuteTextCommand("SELECT a.TagId, a.AssetId, a.Description, " + 
                 "rp.ReadPointLocationId, rp.Comments, DateScanned " + 
                 "FROM AssetsReads ar JOIN Assets a on ar.AssetTagID = a.AssetTagID " + 
                 "JOIN ReadPointLocations rp on " + 
                 "ar.ReadPointLocationsID = rp.ReadPointLocationsID " + 
                 "WHERE a.AssetID = '" + asset + "' ORDER BY DateScanned");
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                _assetReads.Clear();

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    ReadPoint ar = new ReadPoint();
                    ar.ReadPointLocationId = int.Parse(dr["ReadPointLocationId"].ToString());
                    ar.ReadpointName = dr["Comments"].ToString();
                    ar.DateScanned = DateTime.Parse(dr["DateScanned"].ToString());
                    _assetReads.Add(ar);
                }

                //Check to see if the asset has been seen in the last (MaxTime) minutes
                if (DateTime.Parse(_assetReads[0].DateScanned.ToString()) < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    ///////////////////////
                    //Send notification
                    ///////////////////////
                    continue;
                }

                //Determine the correct route to follow
                Route currentRoute = null;
                foreach (Route rt in _routes)
                {
                    foreach (ReadPoint rp in rt.ReadPoints)
                    {
                        if (_assetReads[0].ReadPointLocationId == rp.ReadPointLocationId)
                        {
                            currentRoute = rt;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (currentRoute != null)
                        break;
                }

                //Check if the route was correctly followed
                if (currentRoute != null)
                {
                    //////////////////////////////
                    //This is where I'm stuck
                    //////////////////////////////
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a way of knowing if the truck was coming or going when it passed the reader?)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you're *really* close here. You have a list of the ReadPointLocations (gates) the Asset (truck) has been through, in the order the truck went through the gates. You also have a list of the "proper" paths through these gates, and can identify which one should have been followed, based on which gate the truck went through first. The only thing left to do is to line up the truck's gate reads next to the expected reads, and verify that the truck went through all the gates it should have, in order:

```
//Check if the route was correctly followed
if (currentRoute != null)
{
    var gatesInOrder = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<_assetReads.Length; i++)
    {
       if(_assetReads[i].ReadPointLocationId == currentRoute[gatesInOrder])
          //gate crossed in order; increment to next gate
          gatesInOrder++;           
    }
    //if we didn't get to the end of the route, send a notification
    if(gatesInOrder != currentRoute.Length)
    {
       ///////////////////////
       //Send notification
       ///////////////////////
    }
}
```

Now, this assumes two things. First, that all reads are performed without error. I can tell you from experience that location scans are missed with a very high frequency, even in automated systems. This means that if your entry gate scan was missed, you won't be able to determine which gate the truck should have exited through; you'll pick a Route (probably Gate 1) based on the first read you have, which is the scale entry gate, but because that node is common to both the Gate 1 and Gate 2 paths, you'll falsely notify that the truck exited through the wrong gate if the truck exits through Gate 2, even if it entered through Gate 2. In order to avoid this, you'll have to be able to identify gates in each Route that are unique to that Route (in this case, the entry and exit gates) and identify the proper route to use based on the first gate scan for one of those locations, and not just any location. You'll now have picked the proper route, but you won't find the entry gate scan; you can detect this and send a different "gate scan missed" notification.

Second, we assume that once a truck enters a route, that it must continue through that path and cannot deviate at any point. Nothing can be done out of order. So, in a more complex example, let's say the truck also goes through a simple inspection (taillights working, no visible leaks, tire tread OK, no billowing smoke at idle, etc). If the inspection and weighing can happen in either order, you would falsely send a notification with the above algorithm if the weighing and inspection happened in the opposite order than expected. You can avoid this naively by simply checking that all of the proper path's locations were scanned at some point, but that wouldn't catch, for instance, a truck going the wrong way through the whole thing. If that's possible then you'll need something more complex, such as an overall route map with conditional paths (you may proceed either to the weighing or the inspection gate from either entry gate, then from the inspection exit if you haven't been weighed you must proceed to the weighing entry and vice-versa, while if you have been through both sub-paths, you must proceed to exit gate 1 if you went through entry gate 1, or exit 2 if you entered through entry 2.